# How to redirect to a default hostname

Tags: redirect, dns, webserver, hostname

I want something like:

"http://www.anyhostname.com" ==> "http://192.168.0.1"

i.e. I want to redirect any request other than "192.168.0.1" to "http://192.168.0.1"

I am using Lighttpd as my webserver and dnsmasq as my DNS server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem. Posting the solution here back with hope that it helps somebody in the future...

I solved this by modifying the lighttpd.conf file. I added the following inside my lighttpd.conf file:

```
$HTTP["host"] !~ "mydesiredhostname\.com" {
        url.redirect = (
                                "" => "http://192.168.0.1/"
                        )
}
```

Thank you everybody for your time. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have to wonder if you're doing [transparent proxying](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-2.html) -- if so, there may be better mechanisms to accomplish what you want to do than literally doing what you outlined as your goal.

But if you want to keep going this route, I think you can use lighttpd's [`mod_evhost`](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs%3aModEVhost) facility to easily use a default site configuration:

> General Example:
>
> ```
> server.document-root = "/home/user/sites/default/site"   
> evhost.path-pattern  = "/home/user/sites/%0/site/"
> ```
>
> If `example.org` is requested, and
>   `/home/user/sites/example.org/site/` is
>   found, that path becomes the docroot.
>
> If `example.net` is requested but no
>   directory named
>   `/home/user/sites/example.net/site/`
>   exists, then the docroot remains
>   `/home/user/sites/default/site`

If you have specific hostnames that you want to handle, you can add them to `/etc/hosts` and your `dnsmasq` will serve them. This would work if you had a few hundred hosts/domains that you wanted to handle, but if you wanted to handle *everything*, then dnsmasq may not be the right tool.

I know that [PowerDNS's PipeBackend](http://doc.powerdns.com/pipebackend-dynamic-resolution.html) can be used to easily give the same answer regardless of DNS question; this way, you could easily intercept requests and handle [some or all](http://doc.powerdns.com/backends-detail.html#pipebackend) requests specially. This way, you could answer `192.168.0.1` for *every* request, for *some* requests, or anything you can program.

Comment: Do you have any idea how this can be achieved specifically with lighttpd or dnsmasq?

Comment: Lighttpd looks like it can, look at the documentation for the `mod_evhost` for details; the little "general example" I copied shows that it can be done in roughly two lines of configuration. I don't think dnsmasq can do what you what for _all_ domains, but handling a few hundred through `/etc/hosts` should be easy.

Comment: I don't have multiple sites running on my webserver... I just want to ensure that for any damn request other than my hostname, the request gets redirected to "http://192.168.0.1" by default... Can this be achieved?